# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' - while executing pip3

Tags: python

I installed pip3 using "brew install python3" on mac.

> brew install python3

```
Warning: python@3.9 3.9.2_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.9.2_1, run:
  brew reinstall python@3.9
```

> python3 --version

returns, Python 3.8.2

I dont know how to change it to point to version 3.9.2 the latest version.

Now, I have the following in requirements.txt,

```
sklearn
pandas
```

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Am new to python and not sure how to fix it.

Comment: This most likely is because of your `$PATH`. Check which path is used: `which python`.

Answer (score 2):

Download the get-pip.py file and store it in the same directory as python is installed.
or

**Use the following command to download pip directly.**

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

**Now execute the downloaded file using below command**

python3 get-pip.py

**Verification of the Installation process:**

One can easily verify if the pip has been installed correctly by performing a version check on the same. Just go to the command line and execute the following command:

pip3 --version

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS what helped me is the complete reinstallation of the `python3` with `brew`:

```
brew uninstall python3  # if python3 worked before
brew install python3
```

Then the `pip` started to work again as before.